# How to read data from a file and create an object and assign it to an array?

Tags: java, object, geometry, java.util.scanner

GeometricObjectsData.txt

```
“CIRCLE”, 1, “blue”, true
“RECTANGLE”, 1, 2, “blue”, true
“RECTANGLE”, 10, 2, “red”, true
“CIRCLE”, 2, “green”
“RECTANGLE”
“CIRCLE”
```

Driver: I'm a bit confused on how to transfer the above information into an object and then assign it to an array.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Driver {
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("C:/Users/Charles/Desktop/GeometricObjectsData.txt"));

    ArrayList<GeometricObject> list = new ArrayList<GeometricObject>();

    while (input.hasNext()) {
        String line = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println(line);
    }
  }
}
```

I also have created 3 other classes called GeometricObject, Circle, and Recetangle if you want to see the code for them. The information above indicates the type of figure and the given parameters of radius, length, width, color, and filled.

Comment: We will most likely need the other classes, but try using line.split(",") on each line you read in to get an array of the values you need. then create objects with those values. Are you getting any errors, problems? Please provide more info on the issue you are having

Answer (score 0):

As microsby0 said, you could probably split the raw words into arrays. I don't believe there is an easy way to directly convert a raw word into a class name ((Circle)"Circle" doesn't work and is what I believe is confusing you). You should read each array into certain parameters and process them:

`/*somewhere else in code:*/ shapeArray[i] = convert(array[0],array[1],...)//where i is some incremental value in a loop`

```
Shape convert(String s, int someNumber,...) {
  Shape c;
  switch(s) {
    case "Circle":
      c = new Circle(...);
    break;
    case "Square"
      ...
    break;
    //and so on
  }

 //more application logic
 return c;
 }
```

Convert can return a shape which you can assign to an array of shapes. You can always use [function(method) 'overloading'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading) to handle different inputs.

Answer (score 0):

PSUEDOCODE is used:

I probably wouldn't use a Scanner but

```
BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
```

then you would

//this should split the text of each line into an array

```
String buf[]= null;
    while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {

        resultLine += line + ";";
        buf = resultLine.split(";");

    }
    buffer.close();
```

then looped through the array buf and do

```
if(buf[i].startsWith("C"))
```

then do another split on buf[i] using "," into another array like String arr[]

```
arr = buf[i].split(",");
```

then but the elements of the second array in the Circle Class like

```
Circle circle = new Circle(arr[0],arr[1],etc
```

then add to an array

```
Object result[] = new Object[100];
result[0] = circle;
```