# How to create an object from data in a file and assign it to an array?

Tags: java, arrays, object, geometry, area

I need to take information from a file and create them into objects and put them into an array so I can compare the areas of the objects and list in the array which object has the largest area and its location in the array.

I'm confused on how I take the information from the file and create each one into a object (circle or rectangle) and then assign that object into an array after it has been created. I think my other classes are fine, I'm just stuck on finishing the driver.

Normally, I would do something like Circle c1 = new Circle(); to create a new object, but how do I do that from a file with predefined information and assign it to an array?

Data:

```
“CIRCLE”, 1, “blue”, true
“RECTANGLE”, 1, 2, “blue”, true
“RECTANGLE”, 10, 2, “red”, true
“CIRCLE”, 2, “green”
“RECTANGLE”
“CIRCLE”
```

Driver:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Driver {
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("C:/Users/Charles/Desktop/GeometricObjectsData.txt"));

    ArrayList<GeometricObject> list = new ArrayList<GeometricObject>();

    while (input.hasNext()) {
        String line = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println(line);
    }
  }
}
```

GeometricObject:

```
public abstract class GeometricObject {
    //class variables
    private String color;
    private boolean filled;

    //constructors
    public GeometricObject() {
        super();
        color = "white";
        filled = false;
    }

    public GeometricObject(String color, boolean filled) {
        super();
        this.color = color;
        this.filled = filled;
    }

    //mutators
    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public boolean isFilled() {
        return filled;
    }

    public void setFilled(boolean filled) {
        this.filled = filled;
    }

    //user-defined methods
    public abstract double getArea();

    public abstract double getPerimeter();

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return super.toString() + " \tColor=" + this.getColor() + " \tFilled=" + this.isFilled();
    }

}
```

Circle:

```
 public class Circle extends GeometricObject {
//class variables
private double radius;

//constructors
public Circle() {
    super();
    radius = 1;
}

public Circle(double radius, String color, boolean filled) {
    super(color, filled);
    this.radius = radius;
}

//mutators
public double getRadius() {
    return radius;
}

public void setRadius(double radius) {
    this.radius = radius;
}

//user-defined methods
@Override
public double getArea() {
    //area of a circle
    return (radius * radius * Math.PI);
}

@Override
public double getPerimeter() {
    //perimeter of a circle
    return (2 * radius * Math.PI);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return super.toString() + "\nCircle: Radius=" + this.getRadius();
    }

}
```

Rectangle:

```
public class Rectangle extends GeometricObject {
    //class variables
    private double height;
    private double width;

    //constructors
    public Rectangle() {
        super();
        height = 1;
        width = 1;
    }
    public Rectangle(double height, double width, String color, boolean filled) {
        super(color,filled);
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;
    }

    //mutators
    public double getHeight() {
        return height;
    }
    public void setHeight(double height) {
        this.height = height;
    }
    public double getWidth() {
        return width;
    }
    public void setWidth(double width) {
        this.width = width;
    }

    //user-defined methods
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return super.toString() + "\nRectangle: Height=" + this.height + "\tWidth=" + this.width;
    }
    @Override
    public double getArea() {
        return (height * width);
    }

    @Override
    public double getPerimeter() {
        return (2 * height + 2 * width);
    }

}
```

Comment: You can try using orika to map from your array to the Java objects. I know that's not what you are asking but it might make your code simpler.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read data from a file and create an object and assign it to an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26241322/how-to-read-data-from-a-file-and-create-an-object-and-assign-it-to-an-array)

Comment: where is the assigment/homework mention ?

Answer (score 0):

- In your text file, you have special quotes around your shape items. This will make your life more difficult, so you should change that, if possible
- Example of how to make objects (from your main method):

`while (input.hasNext()) {
        String line = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println(line);
        String[] parts = line.split(",");
        if (parts[0].indexOf("Circle") != -1) {
          Circle c = new Circle();
          // ... parse the rest of the attributes to set up your circle
        } else if ... // fill in the other shape cases
    }`